# Manually Change Speaker Position

Tags: java, audio

Unless I am mistaken, a speaker consists of a floppy metal sheet that has many positions. In Java, is there a way to manually set the position of the speaker? I am looking for something along these lines:

```
...
Speaker.setPosition(byte position);
// or
setSpeakerPosition(byte position);
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Java operates about six levels of abstraction above speaker control, which operates on magnetic fields, not directly on speaker position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are mistaken.  Most speakers are not metal sheets. (If you want to understand how a typical speaker works, try this: http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/speaker.htm)
2. There isn't a way to do that (move the "plate" to a specific position) in Java.  I doubt that it is even possible at the hardware level ... unless the speaker was implemented in a rather strange way / expensive / inefficient way.  On top of that, in a *typical* computer audio system, there are a number of hardware and software components between your program and the speaker plate, none of which are designed to be used that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I never knew that. So, I've figured out another solution to my problem now though!

Answer (score 1):

A speaker plate moves from its resting point in relation to a voltage applied across its terminals. A positive voltage makes the plate move away from the coil and a negative voltage makes it move closer in. You can connect a battery with its constant DC voltage and the plate will move out and stay there (until the speaker burns out) since the speaker at this point is behaving like a resistor. Normal audio signals are AC in nature.

The way a computer system drives a speaker is by sending a series of time series of numeric values to a chip called a D/A converter that converts each specific numeric value to an analog voltage. Next the analog voltage is sent through an amplifier and then finally to the speaker. There are all kinds of APIs for creating the digital signals and routing them to the speaker.

You might think you could then create a digital signal of a constant value as a way of applying DC to the speaker. It won't work though because there is an AC coupling filter at the output of the amplifier specifically for the purpose of protecting the speaker from DC. It's basically a capacitor in series with the speaker.

What you are asking to do is not going to be possible with an audio amplifier like what you'll find in a PC.

You could connect a SW programmable DC power supply connected to an external speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is something in java that works a lot like this.  You just have to understand that sound itself doesn't. If you just set the speaker position to one value and leave it you'll hear at most a brief pulse and then nothing.

If you want it to make noise it has to move.  So you don't just set one position.  You set a bunch, changing the value over time.  Here's an example:

```
  /** Generates a tone.
  @param hz Base frequency (neglecting harmonic) of the tone in cycles per second
  @param msecs The number of milliseconds to play the tone.
  @param volume Volume, form 0 (mute) to 100 (max).
  @param addHarmonic Whether to add an harmonic, one octave up. */
  public static void generateTone(int hz,int msecs, int volume, boolean addHarmonic)
    throws LineUnavailableException {

    float frequency = 44100;
    byte[] buf;
    AudioFormat af;
    if (addHarmonic) {
      buf = new byte[2];
      af = new AudioFormat(frequency,8,2,true,false);
    } else {
      buf = new byte[1];
      af = new AudioFormat(frequency,8,1,true,false);
    }
    SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    sdl.open(af);
    sdl.start();
    for(int i=0; i<msecs*frequency/1000; i++){
      double angle = i/(frequency/hz)*2.0*Math.PI;
      buf[0]=(byte)(Math.sin(angle)*volume);

      if(addHarmonic) {
        double angle2 = (i)/(frequency/hz)*2.0*Math.PI;
        buf[1]=(byte)(Math.sin(2*angle2)*volume*0.6);
        sdl.write(buf,0,2);
      } else {
        sdl.write(buf,0,1);
      }
    }
    sdl.drain();
    sdl.stop();
    sdl.close();
  }
```

From https://community.oracle.com/thread/1273219

The [`SourceDataLine.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html) used here is not much different from the `Speaker.setPosition()` you imagined.  An array of bytes (or just one byte when the harmonic is turned off) is written to the SourceDataLine every time it loops.  The value of the byte is amplitude. It ranges from -100 to 100 in this case.  The position the speaker takes on will be directly proportional to this value in an ideal speaker.  In a real speaker it's subject to the physical speakers frequency response:

[image]

The frequency response of an ideal speaker would have been a horizontal line from 0Hz to infinity.   If you playing music for dogs or humpback whales this might be an issue.  For most humans though this is close enough to ideal for what we are capable of hearing.  Especially if you add a little base and treble to flatten it out.  Still, this means your ability to control the speaker position accurately is limited to a range of frequencies.

In the listing above they are using math to construct a very simple audio tone.  In particular a sine wave.  It won't sound amazing.  In fact it sounds like what you hear when getting a hearing test.  But believe it or not, everything you've ever heard is really many simple sounds like this added together.  That's what http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform teaches us.

[image]

The `generateTone()` method from the listing above would be in what Fourier Analysis calls the [Frequency Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain).  Here the audio signal is defined based on frequency(s).  The math inside `generateTone()` is transforming that definition into the [Time Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_domain).  Here the audio signal is defined based on positions at any one time.  `SourceDataLine.write()` is requesting that the speakers position be brought to a particular position.

Thus, a way to frame your question is: what java methods control audio from the Time Domain?  `SourceDataLine.write()` is only one of many that work this way.  Any method that can reproduce [sampled audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) (recorded with a microphone) works in the Time Domain.  At any one time it has a desired value for the speakers position.

Other audio API's such as [MIDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html) operate more in the Frequency Domain.  When you strike a particular key on a piano you're asking for a frequency.  There are details that complicate this (harmonics, attack, sustain, etc) but that's the basic idea. Trying to build interesting sounds from math like shown above is what synthesizers do.

There are other audio formats where a byte doesn't directly represent speaker position at a particular time.  Some do compression.  Some are lossy.  But there are certainly many audio formats where a byte does directly represent speaker position.  They have a sample rate which is simply how often the position was measured.

In any case, it all must eventually translate into putting the speakers diaphragm into a particular position at a particular time.

[image]

Comment: Well yes ... but you cannot position the "plate" directly ... which is what the OP wants to do.  A step or pulse wave will cause the plate to move, but you can't reliably position the plate like that. 1) There is no way to calibrate the position.  2) The speaker doesn't dynamically hold the plate at the position, so it is likely to "relax" to a resting position over time.

Comment: I'll let the OP tell us what he want's to do.  Positioning the "plate" is exactly what an audio signal does.  Holding it in one fixed position for a long time is no different then playing a very low frequency sound.  How well any one speaker can support that is simply a hardware detail.  Java doesn't care.  Also note, he never once said how often he'd be calling this method and changing the value.  So be careful with what you assume.

Comment: The OP has told us what he wants.  Methods that move the "plate" to a position specified using a byte.  I'm only assuming that he wants what he asked for ... which is (IMO) a reasonable starting assumption!

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing, except it didn't work earlier.

Comment: How about telling us exactly what didn't work.  Some code with expected results.

Comment: As I was trying to point out in my answer: although you can apply a DC signal the the D/A converter, the analog amplifier has a AC coupling filter which will cause the DC to quickly die away to zero. A filter is almost universal on the output of an amplifier specifically for the purpose of preventing damage to the speaker.